# Transferring cPanel accounts - email question

Tags: domain-name-system, email

We're moving a bunch of sites from one of our cPanel servers to another one. What i'm interested in is the best solution for making sure that mail accounts are not affected by propagation. The cpanel account transfer will transfer all mail from old->new but from the inital DNS change there is always a chance that some mail will be routed to the original server not the new server. Short of asking someone to check both mailboxes for a short time is there a more solid solution we can put in place? We tend to have full control of DNS so we can do what we want from that end if need be.

Let me know if this doesnt make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to lower the TTL on the MX record 24 hours prior to the move to a very low value, such as 5 minutes.  Then when you actually perform the migration, only DNS requests made within the last 5 minutes will cache the old mailserver IP.  After you've determined that everything moved correctly and you are not going to be undoing the migration, set the TTLs back to the normal amount.  You should do this for all records you are moving, too, unless you want web traffic going to the old server.

I'm not certain, but moving accounts off the cPanel system may, in fact, remove the mail configuration for the domains on that account.  That being said, mail that would have been accepted may be rejected after the move.  That's a mixed bag for you, since it will mean that the sending mailservers will put the messages in a retry queue and reattempt delivery at a later date (hopefully using the new MX records, and the new mailhost).  Of course, this does mean there will be a delay for those messages.